# Sorting a mixture of summary and detail rows

Tags: google-sheets

I've pulled in data to a sheet that is structured like so:

```
|1    | SHeader | SHeader | SHeader  ....|
|2    | Summary | Summary | Summary  ....|
|3    | DtHeader| DtHeader| DtHeader ....|
|4    |  Detail |  Detail |
|5    |  Detail |  Detail |
.
.
.
|n   | SHeader | SHeader | SHeader  ....|
|n+1 | Summary | Summary | Summary  ....|
|n+2 | DtHeader| DtHeader| DtHeader ....|
|n+2 |  Detail |  Detail |
|n+3 |  Detail |  Detail |
```

I would like to be able to sort this sheet by one of the summary cells, but I also want the detail to "follow" the summary row (if that makes sense). For example, if we sorted by the summary row such that our sheet is now ordered from `n ... 1` I'd expect the sheet to now look like this:

```
|n    | SHeader | SHeader | SHeader  ....|
|n+1  | Summary | Summary | Summary  ....|
|n+2  | DtHeader| DtHeader|
|n+3  |  Detail |  Detail |
|n+4  |  Detail |  Detail |
.
.
.
|1   | SHeader | SHeader | SHeader  ....|
|2   | Summary | Summary | Summary  ....|
|3   | DtHeader| DtHeader| DtHeader ....|
|4   |  Detail |  Detail |
|5   |  Detail |  Detail |
```

- SHeader = Summary Headers (i.e. Start, End, MEPs...)
- Summary = Summary values
- DtHeader = Detail Headers (Time, hr)
- Detail = Detail values

For instance, in this screenshot you could imagine many of these Summary/Detail sections as we scroll down the sheet.

**Before sort**:
[image: Before]

**After sort**:
[image: After]

P.S. Technically I only need one instance of the Summary `Header` row at the top, but it is duplicated throughout (and it's a rather large dataset). Do I have to sanitize that header by removing the superfluous ones?

Questions from comments:

**Q.** *How many of these boxes are there? How are they arranged?*

**A.** Just to be clear the red boxes were placed on an image of the screenshot for illustration purposes only.

**Q.** Will there always be a empty row between the box and a top line?

**A.** Yes.

**Q.** Will the number of details per summary be constant?

**A.** No. A new set of Summary headers denotes the end of the details section for the previous group.

Comment: Done, added screenshot

Comment: Sure, I'll update with those details. Just heading into a conference call so it may be in a few hrs.

Comment: Added some answers to the comment questions and a before/after screenshot of desired results for illustration purposes.

Comment: I should add that the "Summary Values" are not formulas, just static data (another system crunched all the numbers, not based on the details section). Essentially all data in this sheet is static, without any actual formulaic relationships. The only relationship between the data is through formatting (i.e. Details grouped by a specific summary)

Comment: That's a great idea!